# How to stub helper method in acceptance test with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have an acceptance spec using Capybara.  However I would like to stub out one helper method (which provides configuration and I want to test different configurations).  How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to stub the configuration instead? It's a very bad idea to stub your code in an acceptance test.

If you insist this is the best way, you can try:

```
ActionView::Base.any_instance.stub(:the_helper_method) { "other implementation" }
```

Comment: You are right, that was a very bad idea.  I had poorly designed helper.  To fix it, I've introduced non-ActiveRecord model which kept whole configuration and provided various methods to access particular settings.  All those methods were relying on `AppConfig.file_content`, which was returning parsed YAML (configuration file content).  Then I was able to stub it alike `AppConfig.stub(:file_content){some_structured_data}`.  Thanks for pointing me wrong approach!